# Retrieve NTP server status

Tags: bash, shell, ntp

I'm writing a script and the script needs to know if NTP server is accessible, if not, an error message will be printed out.

I'm running Ubuntu, and I need to accomplish this task without needing to download any third part libraries etc.

I came across ntpq. I kinda get the result I want by running the following command:

```
ntpq -p 8.8.8.8
```

I was hoping that I could use exit code to determine the status of command but unfortunately it seems like ntpq doesn't have any exit codes as it always returns 0.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you post example output of ntpq when successful and when not successful?

Comment: Also, is your script in `bash` or another language, e.g. python?

Comment: It's in python. I have as of now no way of knowing when it's successful or not via the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu documentation for ntpq](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ntpq.1.html)

> One of the following exit values will be returned:
>
> ```
> 0 (EXIT_SUCCESS)
>    Successful program execution.
>
> 1 (EXIT_FAILURE)
>    The operation failed or the command syntax was not valid.
> ```

However, `ntpq` is intended for managing NTP servers that you control. A better option for testing the accessibility of other NTP servers is to use `ntpdate` with its `-q` option to

> Query only - don't set the clock.

Examples:

```
$ ntpdate -q example.org
server 93.184.216.34, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
21 Jan 17:53:00 ntpdate[11652]: no server suitable for synchronization found

$ echo $?
1

$ ntpdate -q 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.wrong
Error resolving 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.wrong: Name or service not known (-2)
21 Jan 17:52:11 ntpdate[11650]: Can't find host 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.wrong: Name or service not known (-2)
21 Jan 17:52:11 ntpdate[11650]: no servers can be used, exiting

$ echo $?
1


$ ntpdate -q 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 46.4.99.122, stratum 2, offset 0.000625, delay 0.02603
server 62.138.205.79, stratum 2, offset 0.002026, delay 0.03394
server 94.130.184.193, stratum 2, offset -0.000003, delay 0.02867
server 193.30.120.245, stratum 2, offset 0.000738, delay 0.03133
21 Jan 17:52:01 ntpdate[11649]: adjust time server 46.4.99.122 offset 0.000625 sec

$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: This is a good solution but the problem lies in that ntpdate is not installed by default as ntpq is. Therefore I can't really use it.

Comment: I have came to conclusion that ntpdate is the best tool to use to solve my issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Watch out - `ntpdate` is due to be depreciated any time...http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate